# Stack Overflow Web Architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, lamp

This may sound like a weird question but I will give it a shot anyway. What is the Architecture behind Stack Overflow?

We are a bunch of developers and had a bit of a discussion as to what is the Architecture/technology behind this great invention.  :)

Some guess with technology is ASP.NET MVC may be MySQL db, but we could be wrong.

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on Meta Stack Overflow instead: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It's already been asked on Meta.  See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/
or here: http://blog.serverfault.com/post/stack-exchanges-architecture-in-bullet-points/

Answer (score 0):

I believe stack overflow and the stack exchange sites are developed in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this site is built with ASP.NET MVC. [Check this post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/stack-overflow-and-bizspark/).
I don't know how much you are familiar with ASP.NET MVC, but the basic architecture of SO is not that difficult (although SO offers really a lot of features!)